# Which vehicle types are valid for Trimble MAPS trip management?

Tags: trimble-maps

I'm using the Trip Management, Plan Trip API.  The documentation states that the Vehicle Type is an Enum supporting the following options

Auto,
LightDuty,
MidsizeTruck,
Truck

If I call the API and set this to 0 or 3 I get a valid response.  However if I set this to 1 or 2 I get an error stating:-

{"ErrorType":"ArgumentException","Description":"Invalid value passed for routingProfile.vehicleType: 2. Please refer to the documentation.","ErrorCode":null}

Please note my API key is setup for use in EU.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an error in our documentation that has been corrected. The correct enum values are:

```
0 = Auto,
3 = Truck,
11 = LightTruck,
12 = MidsizeTruck
```

Thanks for bringing this to our attention.

Chris Johnson
Technical Writing Manager
Trimble MAPS